# How to parse XML sent to Ruby on Rails via POST?

Tags: android, ruby-on-rails, xml, xml-parsing

I am sending an XML structure to a Rails application from an Android device.  The structure of this XML looks like this:

```
<Updates>
<Update type="1"><Data>...</Data><Something>...</Something></Update>
<Update type="2"><Data>...</Data><Something>...</Something></Update>
<Update type="3"><Data>...</Data><Something>...</Something></Update>
</Updates>
```

I looks as though Rails turns this into a hash.

How can I go through each  tag (this number varies), look grab its type attribute, and then use the data inside the other elements?

I've been struggling with this.

Here is the error I keep getting (TypeError (can't convert String into Integer)):

```
Started POST "/update/index?auth_token=rAyrJgr4w6LNBSXRoYie" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-04-11 23:44:29 -0500
Processing by UpdateController#index as XML
  Parameters: {"Updates"=>{"Update"=>{"type"=>"2", "levelID"=>"7", "S1"=>"1", "S2"=>"0", "S3"=>"0"}}, "auth_token"=>"rAyrJgr4w6LNBSXRoYie"}
WARNING: Can't verify CSRF token authenticity
  User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."authentication_token" = 'rAyrJgr4w6LNBSXRoYie' LIMIT 1
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
   (0.5ms)  UPDATE "users" SET "current_sign_in_at" = '2012-04-12 04:44:29.385406', "sign_in_count" = 2, "updated_at" = '2012-04-12 04:44:29.386311' WHERE "users"."id" = 1
   (2.2ms)  commit transaction
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 9ms

TypeError (can't convert String into Integer):
  app/controllers/update_controller.rb:21:in `fetch'
  app/controllers/update_controller.rb:21:in `block in index'
  app/controllers/update_controller.rb:19:in `each'
  app/controllers/update_controller.rb:19:in `index'


  Rendered /Users/colegroff/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@exterminator/gems/actionpack-3.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.erb (50.2ms)
  Rendered /Users/colegroff/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@exterminator/gems/actionpack-3.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.erb (1.8ms)
  Rendered /Users/colegroff/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@exterminator/gems/actionpack-3.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.erb within rescues/layout (55.6ms)
----------------------------------------------------
params[:Updates].class: ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess
----------------------------------------------------
update.inspect: ["type", "2"]
```

Here is my controller:

```
class UpdateController < ApplicationController

  before_filter :authenticate_user!

  def index

    output = ""

    puts "----------------------------------------------------"
    puts "params[:Updates].class: #{params[:Updates].class.to_s}"
    puts "----------------------------------------------------"

    if !params[:Updates].nil?
      params[:Updates][:Update].each do |update|
        puts "update.inspect: #{update.inspect}"
        puts "update.fetch(\"type\"): #{update.fetch("type")}"
        puts "update.fetch(\"type\").class.to_s: #{update.fetch("type").class.to_s}"
        update_type = update.fetch("type")
        puts "update_type: #{update_type}"

        case update_type

        when "0"
          puts "inside case 0"
          number_of_bug_bucks = update.fetch("numberOfBugBucks")
          update_bug_bucks(number_of_bug_bucks)
          output += "<Update type='0'>"
          output += "<numberOfBugBucks>#{current_user.bug_bucks.to_s}</numberOfBugBucks>"
          output += "</Update>"
        when "2"
          puts "inside case 2"
          level_id = update.fetch("levelID")
          star_1 = update.fetch("S1")
          star_2 = update.fetch("S2")
          star_3 = update.fetch("S3")
          updated_level = update_level_data(level_id, star_1, star_2, star_3)
          output += "<Update type='2'>"
          output += "<levelID>#{updated_level[0].level_id}</levelID>"
          output += "<S1>#{updated_level[0].star_1}</S1>"
          output += "<S2>#{updated_level[0].star_2}</S2>"
          output += "<S3>#{updated_level[0].star_3}</S3>"
          output += "</Update>"
        when "3"
          puts "inside case 3"
          tower_id = update.fetch("towerID")
          tower_state = update.fetch("towerState")
          updated_tower = update_tower_data(tower_id, tower_state)
          output += "<Update type='3'>"
          output += "<towerID>#{updated_tower[0].tower_id}</towerID>"
          output += "<towerState>#{updated_tower[0].tower_state}</towerState>"
          output += "</Update>"
        when "4"
          puts "inside case 4"
          authentication_token = update.fetch("AuthToken")
          update_is_logged_in = update_is_logged_in(authentication_token)
          output += "<Update type='4'>"
          output += "<AuthToken>#{update_is_logged_in[0].authentication_token}</AuthToken>"
          output += "</Update>"
        end

        puts "----------------------------------------------------"

      end
    end

    puts "output: #{output}"
    puts "----------------------------------------------------"

    respond_to do |format|
      format.xml { render :xml => "<Updates>" + output + "</Updates>" }
    end

  end

  private # private methods below:

    def update_bug_bucks(number_of_bug_bucks)
      current_user.update_attribute("bug_bucks", number_of_bug_bucks)
    end

    def update_level_data(level_id, star_1, star_2, star_3)      
      updated_level = Level.where("level_id = ? AND user_id = ?", level_id, current_user.id)      
      if updated_level.empty?
        current_user.levels.create(attributes = {:level_id => level_id, :star_1 => star_1, :star_2 => star_2, :star_3 => star_3})
      else
        updated_level[0].update_attributes(:star_1 => star_1, :star_2 => star_2, :star_3 => star_2)
      end      
      updated_level      
    end

    def update_tower_data(tower_id, tower_state)      
      updated_tower = Tower.where("tower_id = ? AND user_id = ?", tower_id, current_user.id)      
      if updated_tower.empty?
        current_user.towers.create(attributes = {:tower_id => tower_id, :tower_state => tower_state})
      else
        updated_tower[0].update_attributes(:tower_state => tower_state)
      end      
      updated_tower      
    end

    def update_is_logged_in(authentication_token)      
      logged_out_user = User.where("authentication_token = ?", authentication_token).first
      logged_out_user.reset_authentication_token!
      logged_out_user.update_attribute("is_logged_in", false)      
    end
    ############################################################################################################################
    ############################################################################################################################

end
```

Answer (score 4):

This might be bit late but for anyone who refers this article later this is how I solved a similar situation

```
string = request.body.read # rather than using params you can get get/post message with this
```

then use [Nokogiri](https://rubygems.org/gems/nokogiri) as follows

```
doc = Nokogiri::XML(string)
doc.xpath("//Upadate")
```

for more info how to use Nokogiri please refer the http://nokogiri.org/tutorials

Comment: I parse xml string, using `Hash.from_xml` for simplicity (Rails v4.2.1). Here is the [reference](http://apidock.com/rails/Hash/from_xml/class) for this function.

Comment: nokogiri.org seems down since January 2019 => https://web.archive.org/web/20181118110111/http://www.nokogiri.org/tutorials/

Answer (score 1):

Have you already tried something like

```
params[:updates][:update].each do |update|
  puts "do something with this update: #{update.inspect}"
end
```

If rails gives you a hash, just iterate over the collection in the hash you want to. What does your controller that handles the POST look like?

Comment: I've done what you suggested.  I also edited my original post to show the error I'm getting and my controller.  Why does "TypeError (can't convert String into Integer)" keep happening?

Comment: It seems that sometimes "update" in the loop is sometimes a HashWithIndifferentAccess and sometimes it is an Array.  What could be the solution?

Comment: If it's an array, the indices *must* be integers (so `update.fetch("type")` fails because update is an array). Based on that XML, I think Rails should have a params[:Updates] that is a `HashWithIndifferentAccess` that contains a `HashWithIndifferentAccess` of Updates, that are themselves `Arrays`. So instead of getting back an Update object that you can call `.fetch` on, you're getting an `Array` that has "type" at index 0 and "n" at index 1. Your code is SO close to working, but it's just not handling the Update objects correctly yet.

Comment: I've figured it out!  I will post updated code soon.  But, basically what you just said, if there is only one update, then I treat this update as an `Array`, else treat it like a `HashWithIndifferentAccess`.  Is there any way I would've known that Rails handles requests differently like this?

Comment: Doubtful, I think Rails generally expects that you'll call .each on the collection and be done with it. Glad you got that working! :-D